# Chrome: Uninstall Vuze Remote

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

OS: Windows XP; Chrome version 14.0.835.186

I accidentally installed Vuze Remote and now I have this piece of sh.. toolbar appearing on my Chrome.

Uninstalling this extension (via the extensions menu) does not work: it keep coming back up a few seconds after Chrome is restarted. The same goes for deletion of the respective directory under %user%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions.

I Googled this problem but to no avail. In particular this suggestion, http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=067e5712086d06f0&hl=en, seems like a hoax (at best).

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

[answering my own question].

Succeeded! Below is the sequence of steps that achieved that. Note, however, that is is possible that only the last step is really needed (but I'm not going to reinstall VuzeRemote just to find out) so I suggest that you start from the *last* step.

- Uninstalled Vuze and Chrome
- Restarted the computer
- Deleted c:\program files\vuze remote, c:\program files\vuze, c:\program files\google\chrome
- Deleted F:\Documents and Settings\imaman\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Extensions\ojpijjmpahflnipadmlpgbjmagmjchkk
- Reinstalled Chrome
- Opened Regedit and removed HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\Extensions\ojpijjmpahflnipadmlpgbjmagmjchkk